# Level Selector with possible future levels? [Unity]

Tags: unity

I have a level select screen which is a simple grid layout of my levels. The level data comes from a scriptable object for each level.

The problem I have is what is the best method for populating the grid of levels that use the scriptable object and is able to add more levels to the grid layout if let's say I add an asset bundle in the future?

My thought was that I use a levelDB which holds a list of all of the scriptable objects. Then when an asset bundle is used then it adds the content to the levelDB. The UI would then just use this levelDB to populate the screen.

NOTE: I have very little to no knowledge of how asset bundles work and what you can, and cannot do with them.

Comment: This sounds like a valid plan. Did you try it? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I have not tried it as I am pretty confident it would work. I was hoping that someone could point me to a better plan as this plan still requires me to know the name of the asset bundle. whereas I would love to be able to publish an asset bundle and auto downloads to the game. who knows maybe my current plan can still do that with maybe a mysql table.